# HTML/CSS Image center alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a website where the homepage looks like the this :

[image]

I want to move the ficstore logo in the middle and split the bar into two halves and put one on either side , like this :
[image]

I've split my bar image into two different parts for each side and tried to put the images in different columns. But it just doesn't seem to work.

This is the snippet for the current code :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
                        <h2 style="font-family:helvetica;"><span>Home Page</span></h2>

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" class="img-responsive right" style="width:400px; z-index:1;" />
        </div>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" class="img-responsive right" style="position: absolute; margin-top: 135px; z-index: -2;" />
    </div>
<hr class="style18" />
```

Can someone help?

I've tried the following code as well :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <h2 style="font-family:helvetica;"><span>Book Info</span></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-row">
            <div>
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" class="img-responsive right" style="width:400px; z-index:1;" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/100/" class="img-responsive right" style="position: absolute; margin-top: 135px; z-index: -2;" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/100/" class="img-responsive right" style="position: absolute; margin-top: 135px; z-index: -2;" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<hr class="style18" />
```

Css :

```
.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: There are only 2 `img`s in your code. And what version of bootstrap are you using? 3 or 4?

Comment: There are two images because this code is for the original page with just the bar and the logo.

Comment: I'm using Angular 2. How do I find the bootstrap version?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] in the question. If I was to copy your code and run it, I'd get "Home Page" and a couple of broken images. You can use a service like [lorempixel.com](http://lorempixel.com) to use placeholder images.

Comment: if you're using the CDN, inspect your page and look at the version # in the URL path, or just browse to the script either on your site or via the CDN and it should be commented at the top.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan How do the images matter? I just want to know how to align them. Would you like me to submit the entire code for the home page?

Comment: Obviously not, since I posted a link to an article about creating a **Minimal** example. If you don't want to provide people with example images, that's your choice. The work you put into the question generally correlates to the amount of work people are willing to put into an answer. Good luck.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan  
I added example images. Sorry!

Comment: `<hr>` and `<img>` do not use slashes at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great time to use flex:

HTML:

```
<div class='flex-row'>
  <div><img src="left.png"></div>
  <div><img src="center.png"></div>
  <div><img src="right.png"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to get rid of those inline styles for this to work for you.

Comment: I did. Now my page has a magnified version of my logo in the middle and the left and right images are not aligned either.

Comment: So what is your html look like now?

Comment: <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <h2 style="font-family:helvetica;"><span>Book Info</span></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-row">
            <div>
                <img src="../../../assets/image/logo.png"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="../../../assets/image/left.png"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="../../../assets/image/right.png"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<hr class="style18" />

Comment: Sorry I don't think I can format the code in comments

Comment: If you are going to use flex, you need to ensure you have proper browser prefixes. Also, each item WILL grow to fill the space if you don't put `flex-grow: 0` on the children.

Comment: @SarthakSachdeva, you can format code a bit with backticks: ` before and after your code. The backtick key should be right over the tab key.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it. I would encourage you to ditch whatever framework you are using. `col-x-whatever` is bad news bears.

Here's a fiddle too - with an inline-block way.

https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/fcwyg0zb/

## inline-block

```
.images { 
  text-align: center;
}

.images .image-w {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

### flexbox

```css
.image-w img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.one {
  max-width: 200px;
}

.two {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 1rem;
}

.three {
  max-width: 200px;
}

.images {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<section class='images'>

  <div class='image-w one'>
    <img src='https://placehold.it/300x150' alt='left'>
  </div>
  
  <div class='image-w two'>
    <img src='https://placehold.it/600x300' alt='center'>
  </div>
  
  <div class='image-w three'>
    <img src='https://placehold.it/300x150' alt='right'>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: So you're encouraging people to ditch full featured, cross-browser/cross-device supporting frameworks in favor of a custom made one, so far featuring: a) fixed-width non-responsive columns, b) centering. Supporting all existing devices and browsers with one small amendment: *"works on some, doesn't work on others"*. Did I miss anything?

Comment: Yeah. I guess that is what I was saying. I wouldn't give that same advice to everyone. Just someone with a question like this - because they are likely to learn 'the framework' and not CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have to have 3 images. The bar should divided in two. Put the Fictore in the middle then add display:block.